# How do I iterate RDD's in apache spark (scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I use the following command to fill an RDD with a bunch of arrays containing 2 strings ["filename", "content"].

Now I want to iterate over every of those occurrences  to do something with every filename and content.

```
val someRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/*")
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this however.

So what I want is this:

```
foreach occurrence-in-the-rdd{
   //do stuff with the array found on loccation n of the RDD
}
```

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fundamental operations in Spark are `map` and `filter`.

```
val txtRDD = someRDD filter { case(id, content) => id.endsWith(".txt") }
```

the `txtRDD` will now only contain files that have the extension ".txt"

And if you want to word count those files you can say

```
//split the documents into words in one long list
val words = txtRDD flatMap { case (id,text) => text.split("\\s+") }
// give each word a count of 1
val wordT = words map (x => (x,1))  
//sum up the counts for each word
val wordCount = wordsT reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
```

You want to use `mapPartitions` when you have some expensive initialization you need to perform -- for example, if you want to do Named Entity Recognition with a library like the Stanford coreNLP tools.

Master `map`, `filter`, `flatMap`, and `reduce`, and you are well on your way to mastering Spark.

Answer (score 27):

You call various methods on the RDD that accept functions as parameters.

```
// set up an example -- an RDD of arrays
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Example")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val testData = Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6,7,8))
val testRDD = sc.parallelize(testData, 2)

// Print the RDD of arrays.
testRDD.collect().foreach(a => println(a.size))

// Use map() to create an RDD with the array sizes.
val countRDD = testRDD.map(a => a.size)

// Print the elements of this new RDD.
countRDD.collect().foreach(a => println(a))

// Use filter() to create an RDD with just the longer arrays.
val bigRDD = testRDD.filter(a => a.size > 3)

// Print each remaining array.
bigRDD.collect().foreach(a => {
    a.foreach(e => print(e + " "))
    println()
  })
}
```

Notice that the functions you write accept a single RDD element as input, and return data of some uniform type, so you create an RDD of the latter type. For example, `countRDD` is an `RDD[Int]`, while `bigRDD` is still an `RDD[Array[Int]]`.

It will probably be tempting at some point to write a `foreach` that modifies some other data, but you should resist for reasons described [in this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394286/modify-collection-inside-an-spark-rdd-foreach).

**Edit: Don't try to print large `RDD`s**

Several readers have asked about using `collect()` and `println()` to see their results, as in the example above. Of course, this only works if you're running in an interactive mode like the Spark REPL (read-eval-print-loop.) It's best to call `collect()` on the RDD to get a sequential array for orderly printing. But `collect()` may bring back too much data and in any case too much may be printed. Here are some alternative ways to get insight into your `RDD`s if they're large:

1. `RDD.take()`: This gives you fine control on the number of elements you get but not where they came from -- defined as the "first" ones which is a concept dealt with by various other questions and answers here.

   ```
   // take() returns an Array so no need to collect()
   myHugeRDD.take(20).foreach(a => println(a))
   ```
2. `RDD.sample()`: This lets you (roughly) control the fraction of results you get, whether sampling uses replacement, and even optionally the random number seed.

   ```
   // sample() does return an RDD so you may still want to collect()
   myHugeRDD.sample(true, 0.01).collect().foreach(a => println(a))
   ```
3. `RDD.takeSample()`: This is a hybrid: using random sampling that you can control, but both letting you specify the exact number of results and returning an `Array`.

   ```
   // takeSample() returns an Array so no need to collect() 
   myHugeRDD.takeSample(true, 20).foreach(a => println(a))
   ```
4. `RDD.count()`: Sometimes the best insight comes from how many elements you ended up with -- I often do this first.

   ```
   println(myHugeRDD.count())
   ```

Comment: Isn't there the risk that the different workers will print in some uncoordinated fashion, mixing up their lines? If it works anyway, is this documented?

Comment: @EOL Yes, I was being sloppy -- I just edited my answer to add `collect()` calls when printing `RDD`s.

Comment: Nice, provided complete example even showing setup of sc!

Comment: How would you do it if you had a reasonably big RDD that if you call collect() on it, you would run out of memory?

Comment: @billy_b29 I think if the `RDD` is big enough for this to be a problem you're not going to want to print it all to the console anyway. I only added the `collect()` so the results could be printed cleanly. Since this keeps coming up I've added some solutions to the end of my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: @SpiroMichaylov Thanks for your reply. My intention was actually not to print all of the elements in an RDD, but to call a method for each one of them. And I think I can do that with the map for now... Thanks again.

Comment: Is `collect` a acceptable to be used with large amount of data in production environment?

Comment: @deFreitas In general I would say no, but, as per my exchange with @cpu_meltdown, it's best to be clear about what you're going to use `collect()` for. In the answer above I was using it to print diagnostics to a console, but you certainly won't be doing **that** with large RDDs in production.  I have edited the answer to try to make it clear that `collect()` is only used for diagnostics.

Answer (score 2):

I would try making use of a partition mapping function. The code below shows how an entire RDD dataset can be processed in a loop so that each input goes through the very same function. I am afraid I have no knowledge about Scala, so everything I have to offer is *java* code. However, it should not be very difficult to translate it into scala.

```
JavaRDD<String> res = file.mapPartitions(new FlatMapFunction <Iterator<String> ,String>(){ 
      @Override
      public Iterable<String> call(Iterator <String> t) throws Exception {  

          ArrayList<String[]> tmpRes = new ArrayList <>();
          String[] fillData = new String[2];

          fillData[0] = "filename";
          fillData[1] = "content";

          while(t.hasNext()){
               tmpRes.add(fillData);  
          }

          return Arrays.asList(tmpRes);
      }

}).cache();
```

Comment: Does this actually get run in parallel? I thought anytime a for or while loop is called in an anonymous function in Spark, it gets run sequentially in a single executor

Comment: @JimLohse  Yes it does.

Comment: @thebluephantom Sorry for confusion you mean yes it does run in parallel? Or yes it runs sequentially? Thanks, this was three years ago probably on Spark 1.6 and I haven't used it since late 2016

Comment: It runs in parallel, also then.

Answer (score 1):

what the `wholeTextFiles` return is a Pair RDD:

> def wholeTextFiles(path: String, minPartitions: Int): RDD[(String, String)]
>
> Read a directory of text files from HDFS, a local file system (available on all nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI. Each file is read as a single record and returned in a key-value pair, where the key is the path of each file, the value is the content of each file.

Here is an example of reading the files at a local path then printing every filename and content.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("scala-test").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
sc.wholeTextFiles("file:///Users/leon/Documents/test/")
  .collect
  .foreach(t => println(t._1 + ":" + t._2));
```

the result:

```
file:/Users/leon/Documents/test/1.txt:{"name":"tom","age":12}

file:/Users/leon/Documents/test/2.txt:{"name":"john","age":22}

file:/Users/leon/Documents/test/3.txt:{"name":"leon","age":18}
```

or converting the Pair RDD to a RDD first

```
sc.wholeTextFiles("file:///Users/leon/Documents/test/")
  .map(t => t._2)
  .collect
  .foreach { x => println(x)}
```

the result:

```
{"name":"tom","age":12}

{"name":"john","age":22}

{"name":"leon","age":18}
```

And I think `wholeTextFiles` is more compliant for small files.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (element <- YourRDD)
{
     // do what you want with element in each iteration, and if you want the index of element, simply use a counter variable in this loop beginning from 0 
     println (element._1) // this will print all filenames
}
```

Comment: please add some detail to this answer, maybe a fuller example, in its current state this isn't a great answer

Comment: Each item will use by element._1 for file name and element. _2 for content in the for loop,