# pyspark: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I am getting this error but i do not know why. 
Basically I am erroring from this code:

```
    a = data.mapPartitions(helper(locations))
```

where data is an RDD and my helper is defined as:

```
    def helper(iterator, locations): 
        for x in iterator:
            c = locations[x]
            yield c
```

(locations is just an array of data points)
I do not see what the problem is but I am also not the best at pyspark so can someone please tell me why I am getting 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable from this code?

Comment: You can not iterate on an rdd in the way you do. Pls have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914789/how-do-i-iterate-rdds-in-apache-spark-scala

Comment: @Mohan : thanks I think I get the idea now but I am still getting the same error. I am now calling this: a = data.mapPartitions(lambda iterator: helper(iterator, locations)). What else am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RDD can iterated by using map and lambda functions. I have iterated through Pipelined RDD using the below method

```
lines1 = sc.textFile("\..\file1.csv")
lines2 = sc.textFile("\..\file2.csv")

pairs1 = lines1.map(lambda s: (int(s), 'file1'))
pairs2 = lines2.map(lambda s: (int(s), 'file2'))

pair_result = pairs1.union(pairs2)

pair_result.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + ','+ b)

result = pair.map(lambda l: tuple(l[:1]) + tuple(l[1].split(',')))
result_ll = [list(elem) for elem in result]
```

> ===> result_ll = [list(elem) for elem in result]
>
> TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable

Instead of this I replaced the iteration using map function

```
result_ll = result.map( lambda elem: list(elem))
```

Hope this helps to modify your code accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the answer that said in another question with below link :
[Can not access Pipelined Rdd in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733799/can-not-access-pipelined-rdd-in-pyspark?rq=1)

You cannot iterate over an RDD, you need first to call an action to get your data back to the driver.
Quick sample:

```
`>>> test = sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
 >>> for i in test:
     ...    print i
     ... 
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     TypeError: 'RDD' object is not iterable`
```

but for example you can use '.collect()'

```
`>>> for i in test.collect():
     ...      print i
 1                                                                               
 2
 3`
```