# Pyspark: not able to print after file text is split

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

I am new to spark coding with Python (pyspark).
    I have a txt file in which messages needs to be split at `}{` . That is message starts with `{...}{...}...` like this. I want to split these into

```
{...}
{...}
{...}
```

few also has inner message like

```
{...
    {...}
...
}
```

CODE:
I am trying with below code and I am getting error saying

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonBLEDataParser_work2.py", line 49, in <module>
    for line in words:
TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable
```

(note - i have removed couple of commented lines and hence line number 49 refers to `words = contentRDD.map(lambda x: x.split('}{'))`)

```python
        from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
        #importing re for removing space and others
        import re

        if __name__ == "__main__":

        spark = SparkSession\
                .builder\
                .appName("PythonBLEDataParser")\
                .getOrCreate()

        contentRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile("BLE_data_Sample.txt")\

        #nonempty_lines = contentRDD.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0)
        #print (nonempty_lines.collect())
        words = contentRDD.map(lambda x: x.split('}{'))
        for line in words:
            print (line)

        spark.stop
```

I tried `.map( lambda elem: list(elem))` mentioned in [pyspark: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708338/pyspark-pipelinedrdd-object-is-not-iterable) but didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

After:

```
words = contentRDD.map(lambda x: x.split('}{'))
```

You only did a transformation on contentRDD not an action. This is still a PipelinedRDD object.

If you want to collect it into the driver you need an action like "collect", so:

```
words = contentRDD.map(lambda x: x.split('}{')).collect()
for line in words:
    print (line)
```