# RDD not iterable error

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am practicing some spark code, and starting itself I am stuck with below error.

```
newRDD = sc.textFile("/user/cloudera/sqoop-import/products")
```

> 17/03/15 20:41:31 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored
>   as values in memory (estimated size 198.0 KB, free 419.3 KB) 17/03/15
>   20:41:31 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as
>   bytes in memory (estimated size 23.3 KB, free 442.7 KB) 17/03/15
>   20:41:31 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in
>   memory on 192.168.50.129:49855 (size: 23.3 KB, free: 530.2 MB)
>   17/03/15 20:41:31 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from
>   textFile at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2

```
for i in newRDD:
...     print(i)
...
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: 'RDD' object is not iterable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I iterate RDD's in apache spark (scala)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914789/how-do-i-iterate-rdds-in-apache-spark-scala)

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I did not use any action on data. Only transformation will not get data to the driver program, as all of it is a lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

restart your Linux and and try like this

```
for(el <- newRDD){
println(el)
}
```

the RDDs are not numbers to iterate, you most use loop like above for accessing each element