# How to loop each line in Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am a beginner to Scala and I want to loop through each line which I am reading as below:

```
val data = sc.textFile("D:/Data.csv")
```

Data.csv is like below:

```
1,462,0,NA,0,1,0,Friday,1,5
1,147,33,NA,0,1,0,Friday,1,5
1,105,58,NA,0,1,0,Friday,1,5
1,276,96,NA,0,1,0,Friday,1,5
1,466,1,NA,0,1,0,Friday,1,5
1,466,1,NA,0,1,0,Friday,1,5
1,466,1,NA,0,1,0,Friday,1,5
```

I want to iterate through each line in the above csv and print the 1st and 3 rd column values in each row.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Be aware tha working with Spark and RDD's is very different from regular Scala code.  Your code runs remotely and you can't use loops as normal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I iterate RDD's in apache spark (scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914789/how-do-i-iterate-rdds-in-apache-spark-scala)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val data = sc.textFile("D:/Data.csv")

data.map(_.split(','))
    .foreach(r => println(r(0), r(2)))
```

The `map` call above splits each line in the file on a comma, turning each line into an `Array[String]` and creating a `RDD[Array[String]]`: each element in this `RDD` is an `Array[String]` of the column values in a line.

The `foreach` call prints the first and third column values of each line (i.e., the first and third elements in each `Array[String]` in the `RDD`):

```
(1,0)
(1,1)
(1,1)
(1,33)
(1,1)
(1,58)
(1,96)
```