# How to filter out values from pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a `pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD` called `myRDD`. This is its sample content:

```
[((111, u'BB', u'A'), (444, u'BB', u'A')),
 ((222, u'BB', u'A'), (888, u'BB', u'A')),
 ((333, u'BB', u'B'), (999, u'BB', u'A')),...]
```

I need to delete all entries where the third column values do not coincide. The expected result is this one:

```
[((111, u'BB', u'A'), (444, u'BB', u'A')),
 ((222, u'BB', u'A'), (888, u'BB', u'A')),...]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914789/how-do-i-iterate-rdds-in-apache-spark-scala

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use filter with a lambda expression to check that the third element of each tuple pair are the same such as:

```
l = [((111, u'BB', u'A'), (444, u'BB', u'A')),
     ((222, u'BB', u'A'), (888, u'BB', u'A')),
     ((333, u'BB', u'B'), (999, u'BB', u'A'))]

rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
rdd = rdd.filter(lambda x: x[0][2] == x[1][2])
result = rdd.collect()
print result

>>> [((111, u'BB', u'A'), (444, u'BB', u'A')), ((222, u'BB', u'A'), (888, u'BB', u'A'))]
```

To answer your follow up comment, remember, a lambda is just a function, if you have more complex logic, you can just write it out as a function. You could do something like:

```
def do_stuff(x):
    if (x[0][2] == 'C') or (x[1][2] == 'C'):
        return x     
    else:
        if x[0][2] == x[1][2]: return x
    return None

rdd = rdd.map(do_stuff).filter(lambda x: x is not None)

res = rdd.collect()
```

Comment: It works nicely. By the way, is it possible to add an exception, like excluding the value `C`? If any of pair's third column values is `C`, then no comparison should be done.