# Loading files in a loop in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I  have `n` number of files in a directory with same `.txt` extension and I want to load them in a loop and then make separate `dataframes` for each of them.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914789/how-do-i-iterate-rdds-in-apache-spark-scala) but in my case all my files have same extension and I want to iterate over them one by one and make `dataframe` for every file.

I started by counting files in a directory with following line of code

```
sc.wholeTextFiles("/path/to/dir/*.txt").count()
```

but I don't know how should I proceed further?
Please guide me.

I am using `Spark 2.3` and `Scala`.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want a dataframe for each file? it makes little sense in Spark. Would it not be better if you have only a dataframe where each rows keeps track of the document where it comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wholetextiles returns a paired Rdd Function

```
def wholeTextFiles(path: String, minPartitions: Int): rdd.RDD[(String, String)]
```

You can do map over the rdd, the key of the rdd is path of the file and value is content of the file

```
sc.wholeTextFiles("/path/to/dir/*.txt").take(2)

sc.wholeTextFiles("/path/to/dir/*.txt").map((x,y)=> some logic on x and y )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the hadoop fs and get the list of files under the directory and then iterate it over and save it to differnet dataframes.

Something like the below:

```
// Hadoop FS
val hadoop_fs = FileSystem.get(sc1.hadoopConfiguration)

// Get list of part files
val fs_status = hadoop_fs.listLocatedStatus(new Path(fileFullPath))
while (fs_status.hasNext) {

      val fileStatus = fs_status.next.getPath
      val filepath = fileStatus.toString
      val df = sc1.textFile(filepath)
}
```