# Implementing topological sort in Spark GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, spark-graphx, topological-sort

I am trying to implement [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn.27s_algorithm) using [Spark's GraphX](http://spark.apache.org/graphx/) library.

This is the code I've written so far:

***MyObject.scala***

```
import java.util.ArrayList

import scala.collection.mutable.Queue

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge
import org.apache.spark.graphx.EdgeDirection
import org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph
import org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph.graphToGraphOps
import org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.rddToPairRDDFunctions

object MyObject {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark-App").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val resources: RDD[Resource] = makeResources(sc)
    val relations: RDD[Relation] = makeRelations(sc)

    println("Building graph ...")
    var graph = buildGraph(resources, relations, sc)
    println("Graph built!!")

    println("Testing topo sort ...")
    val topoSortResult = topoSort(graph, sc);
    println("topoSortResult = " + topoSortResult)
    println("Testing topo sort done!")
  }

  def buildGraph(resources: RDD[Resource], relations: RDD[Relation], sc: SparkContext): Graph[Resource, Relation] =
    {
      val vertices: RDD[(Long, Resource)] = resources.map(resource => (resource.id, resource))
      val edges: RDD[Edge[Relation]] = relations.map(relation => Edge(relation.srcId, relation.dstId, relation))
      var graph = Graph[Resource, Relation](vertices, edges)
      graph
    }

  def makeResources(sc: SparkContext): RDD[Resource] =
    {
      var list: List[Resource] = List()
      list = list :+ new Resource(1L)
      list = list :+ new Resource(2L)
      list = list :+ new Resource(3L)
      list = list :+ new Resource(4L)
      list = list :+ new Resource(5L)
      sc.parallelize(list)
    }

  def makeRelations(sc: SparkContext): RDD[Relation] =
    {
      var list: List[Relation] = List()
      list = list :+ new Relation(1L, "depends_on", 2L)
      list = list :+ new Relation(3L, "depends_on", 2L)
      list = list :+ new Relation(4L, "depends_on", 2L)
      list = list :+ new Relation(5L, "depends_on", 2L)
      sc.parallelize(list)

    }

  def topoSort(graph: Graph[Resource, Relation], sc: SparkContext): java.util.List[(VertexId, Resource)] =
    {
      // Will contain the result
      val sortedResources: java.util.List[(VertexId, Resource)] = new ArrayList()

      // Contains all the vertices
      val vertices = graph.vertices

      // Contains all the vertices whose in-degree > 0
      val inDegrees = graph.inDegrees;
      val inDegreesKeys_array = inDegrees.keys.collect();

      // Contains all the vertices whose in-degree == 0
      val inDegreeZeroList = vertices.filter(vertex => !inDegreesKeys_array.contains(vertex._1))

      // A map of vertexID vs its in-degree
      val inDegreeMapRDD = inDegreeZeroList.map(vertex => (vertex._1, 0)).union(inDegrees);

      // Insert all the resources whose in-degree == 0 into a queue
      val queue = new Queue[(VertexId, Resource)]
      for (vertex <- inDegreeZeroList.toLocalIterator) { queue.enqueue(vertex) }

      // Get an RDD containing the outgoing edges of every vertex
      val neighbours = graph.collectNeighbors(EdgeDirection.Out)

      // Initiate the algorithm
      while (!queue.isEmpty) {
        val vertex_top = queue.dequeue()
        // Add the topmost element of the queue to the result
        sortedResources.add(vertex_top)

        // Get the neigbours (from outgoing edges) of this vertex
        // This will be an RDD containing just 1 element which will be an array of neighbour vertices
        val vertex_neighbours = neighbours.filter(vertex => vertex._1.equals(vertex_top._1))

        // For each vertex, decrease its in-degree by 1
        vertex_neighbours.foreach(arr => {
          val neighbour_array = arr._2
          neighbour_array.foreach(vertex => {
            val oldInDegree = inDegreeMapRDD.filter(vertex_iter => (vertex_iter._1 == vertex._1)).first()._2
            val newInDegree = oldInDegree - 1
            // Reflect the new in-degree in the in-degree map RDD
            inDegreeMapRDD.map(vertex_iter => {
              if (vertex_iter._1 == vertex._1) {
                (vertex._1, newInDegree)
              }
              else{
                vertex_iter
              }
            });
            // Add this vertex to the result if its in-degree has become zero
            if (newInDegree == 0) {
              queue.enqueue(vertex)
            }
          })
        })
      }

      return sortedResources
    }

}
```

***Resource.scala***

```
class Resource(val id: Long) extends Serializable {
  override def toString(): String = {
    "id = " + id
  }
}
```

***Relation.scala***

```
class Relation(val srcId: Long, val name: String, val dstId: Long) extends Serializable {
  override def toString(): String = {
    srcId + " " + name + " " + dstId
  }
}
```

I am getting the error :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

for the line `val oldInDegree = inDegreeMapRDD.filter(vertex_iter => (vertex_iter._1 == vertex._1)).first()._2`.

I guess this is because it is illegal to modify an RDD inside the for-each loop of some other RDD.

Also, I fear that `queue.enqueue(vertex)` will not work, since [it is not possible to modify a local collection inside a `for-each` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23396500/1925388).

**How do I correctly implement this topological sort algorithm ?**

The full stack trace of the exception is uploaded [here](https://gist.github.com/Anmol-Singh-Jaggi/95e084d33824c8af97888304a3460d34) *(Had to upload it externally to prevent exceeding the body size limit of StackOverflow)*.

Answer (score 0):

```
vertex_neighbours.foreach(arr => {
      val neighbour_array = arr._2
      neighbour_array.foreach(vertex => {
      . . .
```

The outer foreach could be replaced by a for loop.

Comment: Could you please show the final working version of the code with the changes you mentioned ?

Answer (score 0):

```
val vertex_neighbours = neighbours.filter(vertex => vertex._1.equals(vertex_top._1)).collect()
```

You need to get the RDD before doing for loop over it.