# Why the ForEach sink doesn't called function (show_data_function) in Spark structured streaming?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I want to see the data available in the spark streaming dataframe and later part I want to apply business operation on that data.

So far I have tried to convert streaming DataFrame to RDD. Once that object converted into RDD, I want to apply a function with transform the data and also create new column with the schema( for specific message).

```
dsraw = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_kafka_server) \
    .option("subscribe", topic) \
    .load() \
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")


print "type (df_stream)", type(dsraw)
print "schema (dsraw)", dsraw.printSchema()


def show_data_fun(dsraw, epoch_id):
    dsraw.show()

    row_rdd = dsraw.rdd.map(lambda row: literal_eval(dsraw['value']))
    json_data = row_rdd.collect()

    print "From rdd : ", type(json_data)
    print "From rdd : ", json_data[0]
    print "show_data_function_call"


jsonDataQuery = dsraw \
    .writeStream \
    .foreach(show_data_fun)\
    .queryName("df_value")\
    .trigger(continuous='1 second')\
    .start()

print the first JSON message which is in the stream.
```

Comment: The headline of the question and the explanation are pretty different. Can you also rewrite the question to clearly set what output you expect. And why do you think it's an issue with ForEach ?

Comment: Hi Tej,
I am sorry for the confusion, but can you take a look why foreach sink is unable to call the function (show_data_fun).

Comment: How do you execute the code? Do you use `pyspark` or execute it directly?

Comment: Nowadays, I submit my spark jobs using spark-submit in CDH.

```spark2-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0 <python-spark file>```

Comment: @AkashPatel Is this similar to what you are trying to achieve?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394286/modify-collection-inside-a-spark-rdd-foreach

Comment: @A.Dev similar to this. But my source is DataFrame streaming object so I cannot access this data directly. First I have to expose the data from DataFrame to RDD and then may be I can iterate over it. 
Here, in this case function "show_data_fun" should be called and convert DataFrame to RDD. But this isn't happening and also function is not called by foreach sink on each batch-epoch.